# How to remove the linkable name of a library?

Tags: document-library, view, library

For example my library looks like this:

[image]

Would like to remove the section in the red box, because I need to add this webpart several times in the page filtering for only certain documents, and don't like the idea of seeing the webpart being numbered within  [] each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options, go into edit mode on the page and edit the properties of the web part, setting the Chrome to None or give each web part a unique title, like STE Files from Last Week, Pending STE Files, etc depending on what your filters are on the various views.

Comment: Thank you, setting the Chrome type to None didnt hide this text. But renaming it to something specific  to the section it resides in works better. Although removing it completely would be my preferred way to go.

Comment: Now that you've renamed them differently, does Chrome type None hide them?

Comment: Unfortunately not.